# Knockoutjs + ko.mapping.fromJS + computed field not calculate computed

Tags: knockout.js, computed-observable, computed-values

I try to do this:

```
myData = {weight: 100, anotherWeight: 120.55}; // when my data is plain json - all work

$.when($.getJSON(url, {param}, function(data) {myData = data} ).   
 //when i got it from ajax - dosn't work
then(function(){
  var taskModel = function(data)
  {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
    this.computedWeight = ko.computed(function () { return self.weight() + 
       ' ---- ' + 
       self.anotherWeight() + ' kg'; });
  }
  ko.applyBindings(new taskModel(myData));
});

<input type="text" data-bind="value: weight"/><br/>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: anotherWeight"/><br/>
<span data-bind="text: computedWeight"></span>
```

First time - after loading -  computedWeight is calculate right. But when I change weight or anotherWeight fields - computedWeight don't change.
Thanks.

Comment: Is the right data is returned for the server? What is returned in the success callback? Please have a look on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zEfRj/4/)

Comment: thanks. In jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/EfRj/4/ - all work. But in my case - computed field is not calculated. I will try to investigate the ajax response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `ko.mapping.fromJSON()` instead of `ko.mapping.fromJS()`

Comment: Thanks all.The problem was solved. There is my error. I use custom binding for weight & anotherWeight. In this case simple computed(...) does't work. When I use simple bndig <... data-bind="value: weight"> - all work.<br/>Sorry for question. My eeror.